# Converting WEB application action to script

Tags: curl

I am a using a WEB application to perform a certain action. I would like this action to be scripted.
Someone suggested I use Chrome DevTools to copy the corresponding requests as curl into my script.

I would appreciate your assistance in the translation process as I am not a web application developer.

This is the first call from the Console:

```
 XHR finished loading: POST "https://lmb-demo-server:9443/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.repository.service.internal.discovery.IFriendsAdminRestService/testNewFriend".?include=B~&etag=DnrqNy7Zhdv_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fccm&ss=FhuYs&locale=en-us:6289 xhr?include=B~&etag=DnrqNy7Zhdv_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fccm&ss=FhuYs&locale=en-us:6551 _1.xhr?include=B~&etag=DnrqNy7Zhdv_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fccm&ss=FhuYs&locale=en-us:15405 _1a?include=B~&etag=DnrqNy7Zhdv_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fccm&ss=FhuYs&locale=en-us:15368 handleRequest?include=B~&etag=DnrqNy7Zhdv_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fccm&ss=FhuYs&locale=en-us:15303 jazz.client.xhr?include=B~&etag=DnrqNy7Zhdv_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fccm&ss=FhuYs&locale=en-us:15312 jazz.client.rawXhrPost.jazz.client.xhrPost?include=B~&etag=DnrqNy7Zhdv_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fccm&ss=FhuYs&locale=en-us:21741 _2?exclude=B&include=com.ibm.team.process.web.ui.internal.admin.projects.ProjectAreaManagementMenu~co…:14413 com.ibm.team.repository.web.client.internal.OAuthAdminClient._invokeService?exclude=B&include=com.ibm.team.process.web.ui.internal.admin.projects.ProjectAreaManagementMenu~co…:14388 com.ibm.team.repository.web.client.internal.OAuthAdminClient.testNewFriend?exclude=B&include=com.ibm.team.process.web.ui.internal.admin.projects.ProjectAreaManagementMenu~co…:16383 dojo.declare.testNewFriendProperties?exclude=B&include=com.ibm.team.process.web.ui.internal.admin.projects.ProjectAreaManagementMenu~co…:16376 dojo.declare.saveUpdates?include=B~&etag=DnrqNy7Zhdv_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fccm&ss=FhuYs&locale=en-us:446 (anonymous function)
2014-12-05 07:36:08.247?include=B~&etag=DnrqNy7Zhdv_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fccm&ss=FhuYs&locale=en-us:6289 XHR finished loading: GET "https://lmb-demo-server:9443/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.repository.service.in…endsOAuthInfo?url=https%3A%2F%2Flmb-demo-server%3A9443%2Frs%2Frootservices".
```

How do I convert this one to a curl command?

Thanks,
Liora

Comment: This isn't really on topic for SO, since it's not actually about programming, it's about a feature of Chrome. That said, your problem is that you aren't copying them correctly. If you're in the Developer Tools in Chrome and go to the Network tab, you should be able to right click a request and select "Copy as cURL", which copies an actual cURL command into your clipboard. What you have pasted here isn't the output of that command.

Comment: Your comment was very helpful. Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chris Hayes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1813853/chris-hayes) comment answered my question:

> This isn't really on topic for SO, since it's not actually about programming, it's about a feature of Chrome. That said, your problem is that you aren't copying them correctly. If you're in the Developer Tools in Chrome and go to the Network tab, you should be able to right click a request and select "Copy as cURL", which copies an actual cURL command into your clipboard. What you have pasted here isn't the output of that command.